# Wiring 4-wire PT1000 to MCP3008

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi, temperature, pt100

Is it possible to read a 4-wire PT1000 using an MCP3008, which is connected to a Raspberry Pi?

I can handle the software part; I am looking for how to wire things up.

Is this possible after all? Which additional components are required?

Thanks!

**Update:** adding [datasheet for the MCP3008](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21295d.pdf), thanks Transistor.

**Update 2:** adding [information about the PT1000 RTD](https://www.thermometricscorp.com/pt1000).

**Update 3:** I found a [posting (German)](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/257303) showing how to wire a PT100 to the [MCP3551](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001950F.pdf).

Is is possible to replace the MCP3551 with the MCP3008? How would I wire this?

The MCP3008 has a resolution of 10 bits, as compared to the 22 bits of the MCP3551. This will reduce the accuracy of the readings. Anything else I need to think of?

[image: PT100 MCP2551]

Comment: you could certainly try it ... the MCP3008 has a differential input mode .... the Vref pin on the MCP3551 is an input, same as the MCP3008 ... that means that Vref in the circuit above is derived from a voltage divider connected to Vcc

Answer (score 3):

Temperature dependent resistor based temperature sensors need a circuit which feeds known current through them to generate a temperature dependent voltage. In your own recently inserted example drawing there's a voltage divider. It's non-linear, but that's nothing if you calculate the result with software and the AD conversion resolution is high enough. The numeric conversion result is proportional to Rx/(Rx+R2) where Rx is the resistance of the sensor. The idea has a benefit - no absolute Vref is needed, it's enough the +5V doesn't swing during the conversion (filter R1+C1 is hoped to kill fast changes).

Sensors have often 4 wires because the current feeding wires also have some resistance and the voltage sensing circuit wants to know what's the voltage between the ends of the resistor, the voltage drop in the current feeding wires is not wanted to be summed along.

Then you need a circuit which converts the voltage of the sensor to temperature. Your AD coverter + your program can do the trick. Or not.  Get the resistance vs temperature curve for PT1000, calculate which current through PT1000 can cause a measurable voltage and does the interesting temperature range cause large enough variation to the voltage. You may need an analog circuit which subtracts some base line voltage and amplifies the rest of the voltage to give enough variation in the interesting temperature range.

Know that the dependence resistance vs temperature is not linear, you need a lookup table or nonlinearity approximation functions. You must compensate how much measurement current heats the sensor element and you must be able to filter out the noise. A simple RC filter+software averaging are enough in easy cases. Finally you need a a known well working temperature meter for calibration. Theoretically melting ice and boiling water can be used if the air pressure is known.

The task as a whole is far from trivial. Consider to use something which contains the tricky parts already designed and built. One example: https://www.digikey.dk/catalog/en/partgroup/adafruit-pt1000-rtd-temperature-sensor-amplifier-max31865/77266

Comment: It is very rare and would be very unwieldy to use actual temperature references to calibrate circuitry. Resistances are almost always used, since the sensors are made to be interchangeable within tight limits.

Comment: Thanks @user287001. The formulas for calculating temperature from resistance are available, that part is done in software and should be straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

Reading 4 wire RTDs with good/very good accuracy is not a trivial task. As previously mentioned, accurate current sources are needed to biasing the PT1000 resistances.
VRef kind of sourcing can seem at first instance enough, but surely will not very accurate task. Not only possible VRef fluctuations, but also ADC side effects (input kick-backs etc.). Thus an active driver with OP would be good.

Or you can use modern parts (like AD7124-4) where well adjusted current sources already integrated in IC.
Check an example circuit under Circuit Note CN383.
https://www.analog.com/en/applications/technology/precision-sensor-interface/temperature-sensing/rtd.html